# How to use CFPropertyList in Symfony2?

Tags: symfony

I need to use CFPropertyList in Symfony2, can anybody help me??
I'm trying to 'use' it form its namespace but it does not work.
I placed the library content in vendor/cfpropertylist/CFPropertyList.

Comment: Please give more details about `doesn't work`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for trying to help, I could solve the problem, CFPropertyList is not a Symfony2 Bundle, so i needed to 'require' it form app.php and/or app_dev.php and then 'use' it form its namespace in the controller and it works